# screprt with twoside and scrlayer-scrpage: remove default page number

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

When I manually set the page number to appear in the `\cfoot` with scrlayer-scrpage, I get both page numbers: one in the `\cfoot` and one in the `\ofoot`. The one in the `\ofoot` is only triggered by the `twoside` option of the documentclass. Adding a `\clearpairofpagestyles` directly after loading scrlayer-scrpage makes the header disappear as well, which I find strange - I thought this option was meant to clear the styles *before* defining a new style. Why does it make the header which is loaded *after* it disappear? And how do I get rid of the default page number in the `\ofoot`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\clearpairofpagestyles

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-18]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In addition to page styles plain, empty, headings and myheading, KOMA adds scrheadings,and plain.scrheadings.  There is no easy way to tell what the current page style is, but you can see what happens when you select a different one using \pagestyle or \thispagestyle.

Comment: You are not loading or redefining the header in your code. You are only changing the foot.

Comment: @JohnKormylo headings and scrheadings both print the header and two page numbers, plain and plain.scrheadings only print the two page numbers (as expected) and empty prints no header or footer (as expected). Can I conclude from this that the current page style is either headings or scrheadings? Your comment got me thinking and I simply added ```\ofoot[]{}```, which solved the problem. But I suppose that this isn't very good style? I'm not very good at KOMA-script. I'm trying to learn but I find the documentation a bit hard to grasp, especially the Additonal Information chapters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see. I thought that the ```\markboth``` in ```\AfterTOCHead...``` was loading the header. I'm trying to get a better understanding of KOMA-script but finding it hard to find accessible information for non-programmers.

Comment: \markboth and \chaptermark stores something in a mark, but this stored material is only used if the header definition contains a command like \headmark or \leftmark. If you clear the header than the marks are simply not used.

Comment: and don't worry about not understanding koma script: that is no easy read, even for programmers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for clearing that up! Every answer and comment on stackexchange brings me a tiny step further in understanding at least the basics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `scrlayer-scrpage` sets page style `scrheadings` automatically. Additionaly it redefines `headings` as alias of `scrheadings` (or the main style of the active pair of layer page styles) and `plain` as alias of `plain.scrheadings` (or the plain style of the active pair of layer page styles). On chapter pages `plain` (= the plain style of the active pair of layer page styles) is used.

You could use either

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}% <- outdated macro replaced
}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% short version of \cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}% <- outdated macro replaced
}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\ofoot*{}% short version of \ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% short version of \cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```